# Kivy - Postion of Layout makes problems

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and do my first first steps.
The Syntax looks realy simple, but now i got a problem and I am not able to solve them on my own.

Python-File:

```
#! usr/bin/python3

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

kivy.require("2.0.0")


class MainWindow(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run() here
```

kv-File:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<Mainwindow>:
# weißer Hintergrund
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    # Header Anfang
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50

        # Hintergrundfarbe
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1)        
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 240
            Image:
                source: "images\logo.png"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 40 
            Label:
                text: 'Name'
                font_size: 18
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 200

        # Gelber Streifen
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color: 
                    rgba: (0.83,0.66,0,1)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 3
    # Header Ende

    # Body Anfang
    # Abschnitt 1
    Label:
        color: 0.1,0.1,0.1,1
        bold: "True"
        text: "Headline1"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: 50
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "left"
        valign: "bottom"
        padding_x: 30

    Label:
        canvas:
            Color: 
                rgba: (0.1,0.1,0.1,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos[0] + 30, self.pos[1]
                size: self.width-60, 2
    #GridLayout:
        #cols: 2
        #Button:
        #    text: "B1"
        #    background_color: 1,0,0,1
        #Button:
        #    text: "B2"
        #    background_color: 1,0,0,1
        #Button:
        #    text: "B3"
        #    background_color: 1,0,0,1

    # Body Ende
```

When I run the code, everythings looks correkt, but
if I add the Buttons in the last lines the whole Layout looks confusing.
I don't know this is happening?
If there is something other in the file which is not correct, please tell me.

regards,
Benjamin

Comment: first put `kv` correctly formatted.

Comment: you could add image with incorrect layout and with expected layout.

Comment: you use `cols: 2` but you add three buttons.